# When is it reasonable to violate the Single Responsibility Principle?

Tags: coding-style, design-principles

After refactoring some service-layer classes in our java web application, i was asking myself at which point it is reasonable to stop adhering to the Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) and to keep the maintainability and readability of the code. Now I am asking you about your experience with this issue.

**Example:**

Assuming a UserManager class which does the following:

1. finds users from a database
2. creates new users
3. manipulates existing users

*Case A:* Every of these three responsibilities consists of several methods which perform their tasks.

→ It would be clear for me to split it into three classes.

*Case B:* Every of these three responsibilities consists of only one method.

→ **What would you suggest in this case?** Should this be separated into three tiny classes or left in the UserManager class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, SRP as related to OOP means that state and behavior related to a particular object or entity should all be within a single class. Thus, my opinion is that you would want to keep all methods related to users in a single class, regardless of how many methods there are or how many are needed to carry out a particular task.

The point of SRP (as I see it) is to make sure that you don't have domain objects manipulating one another. In other words, if you (hypothetically) had another class called `AccountManager`, then that class should not have any operation that manipulates a `User` object directly - as this would violate SRP. Rather, the `AccountManager` class would need to rely upon the `UserManager` class to handle any/all user manipulation.